# How to show multiples model data in one view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have built-in models in my project and I want to show data of all the models in one view in table form by using one model.

I am using Entity Framework.

Comment: Define a new class that includes all required instances and pass it as a view data model to your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a ViewModel - which allows you to group multiple properties and models into one, for use in a view.

For example, say you have 2 models

```
Model1.cs
Model2.cs
```

If you want to use both in a view, you can create a new model called "ViewModel1.cs" and set it up like this:

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    public Model1 model1 { get; set; }
    public Model2 model2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can then reference this ViewModel at the top of your view with:

```
@model ViewModel1.cs
```

Allowing you to access both Model1 and Model2 in your view.